# Yet again confused why ssh key auth does not work from WSL on W10 to my Centos 7 server

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-keys

I have ssh keys generated, I have pubkey authentication uncommented and set to yes in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. Anyone see anything I am missing/don't understand in my config? Makes me sad to type my password. ._.

**wsl home ssh folder -- ~/.ssh**

```
weh@workPC:/mnt/c/Users/weh/Downloads$ ls -l ~/.ssh
total 16
-rw------- 1 weh weh  1675 Jun  2 09:27 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 weh weh   399 Jun  2 09:27 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 weh weh 10832 Jul 20 10:41 known_hosts
```

**centos sshd folder /etc/ssh**

```
ls -l /etc/ssh
total 276
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     242153 Apr 12 09:05 moduli
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root       2208 Apr 12 09:05 ssh_config
-rw-------. 1 root root       4471 Jul 27 12:18 sshd_config
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys    227 Apr 23  2016 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        162 Apr 23  2016 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys    387 Apr 23  2016 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root         82 Apr 23  2016 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys   1679 Apr 23  2016 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        382 Apr 23  2016 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

**centos sshd_config file**

```
#$OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.93 2014/01/10 05:59:19 djm Exp $                                                                                      

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See                                                                                          
# sshd_config(5) for more information.                                                                                                                  

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin                                                                                              

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with                                                                                 
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where                                                                                          
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the                                                                                 
# default value.                                                                                                                                        

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell                                                                                  
# SELinux about this change.                                                                                                                            
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER                                                                                                     
#                                                                                                                                                       
#Port 22                                                                                                                                                
#AddressFamily any                                                                                                                                      
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                  
#ListenAddress ::                                                                                                                                       

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1                                                                                                
#Protocol 2                                                                                                                                             

# HostKey for protocol version 1                                                                                                                        
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key                                                                                                                          
# HostKeys for protocol version 2                                                                                                                       
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key                                                                                                                       
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key                                                                                                                      
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key                                                                                                                     
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key                                                                                                                   

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key                                                                                                   
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h                                                                                                                             
#ServerKeyBits 1024                                                                                                                                     

# Ciphers and keying                                                                                                                                    
#RekeyLimit default none                                                                                                                                

# Logging                                                                                                                                               
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging                                                                                                                
#SyslogFacility AUTH                                                                                                                                    
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV                                                                                                                                 
#LogLevel INFO                                                                                                                                          
LogLevel DEBUG                                                                                                                                          

# Authentication:                                                                                                                                       

#LoginGraceTime 2m                                                                                                                                      
#PermitRootLogin yes                                                                                                                                    
#StrictModes yes                                                                                                                                        
#MaxAuthTries 6                                                                                                                                         
MaxAuthTries 2                                                                                                                                          
#MaxSessions 10                                                                                                                                         
MaxSessions 6        
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and may cause several
# problems.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox          # Default for new installations.
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
PermitTunnel yes
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

**ssh from wsl to centos verbose mode**

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for my.spout.com
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 29: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to my.spout.com [8.8.8.8] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/weh/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/weh/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/weh/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/weh/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/weh/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/weh/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/weh/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/weh/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA a7:ff:43:28:6a:f7:1b:3e:25:14:93:57:d3:c9:57:4c
debug1: Host 'my.spout.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/weh/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/weh/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/weh/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/weh/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/weh/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
meh@my.spout.com's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to my.spout.com ([8.8.8.8]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Last login: Thu Jul 27 12:18:22 2017 from 8.8.4.4
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I am confused, are you connecting from the WSL to a remote centos system or the other way around.  Are the config files you shared from the WSL system or the centos system.  What does your .ssh folder and configs look like on the remote system?

Comment: I have the type of debug output listed right above each section between double asteriks. Thats supposed to make text bold in wiki style, but for some reason it doesnt here. Hybrid wiki markup. I am connecting to centos from wsl. I made things clearer up above. Thank you

Comment: Ok, what does the `~/.ssh` folder look like on the centos system you are connecting to?  You have double checked the authorized keys on the remote system?  What do you see in the logs on the remote system when you attempt to login?

Comment: Please, post the permissions and selinux labels of the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and its parent directories.

Comment: selinux was it! Of course it was, never considered it since I hadn't run into selinux issues with ssh keys before :)

Answer (score 0):

Jakuje reminded me about selinux. I have never run into selinux issues with ssh keys, but there's always a first time! My ~/.ssh/* selinux contexts were unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 when they needed to be unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0. After changing the context type, I was able to ssh-copy-id and ssh right in!

Thank you!!